# Matlab: Extracting the entire row of a max value in a matrix

Tags: arrays, matlab, matrix, max

I have a matrix with six columns. I found the max value of a certain column but how would I go about extracting the entire row pertaining to that value?

Answer (score 0):

To extract row 1 of matrix A use `A([1],:)` to extract row 1 and 2 use `A([1,2],:)`

Answer (score 0):

Use the `max()` function as explained [here](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/max.html#bupr8_p). For example

if A is your matrix

```
[M, I] = max(A)
Row = A([I(1)],:)
```

where `I(1)` is used to find the row containing the max element of the first coloumn